# Flutter DeepLinks implementations without using any package, including go_router

Tags: flutter

Handling deeplinks in Flutter is a common usecase and there are many resources to achieve it using `go_router`.

I want to achieve deep links implementation without using any third party packages.
As my usecase is very minimal.

I am getting a deep link likewise (for example)

`https://example.com/news?id=32`

Expected output is to Open `NewsWidget` passing the provided `id` to the Widget.

for example : `NewsWidget(id: 32)`

Till now I have used `named routes` routing and `onGenerateRoute` on `MaterialApp` parent. Didn't get any progress on the same.

Approach One : Using Plain `named` routes.
For this I am not sure, how to extract the :id, if it is hitting the `news route`.
[Using GoRouter showcase this similar pattern approach, but it has `state` param to extract out passed-parameters of the url. ]

```
return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => const HomeScreen(),
        '/news/:id': (_) => const NewsDetailScreen(id : ''),
      },
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
```

Approach Two : Using only `onGenerateRoute` without providing `home`, `initialRoute` and `routes`.

As per current understanding what I feel is, `onGenerateRoute` is the way to go achieve this functionality.
But I am not sure how to extract the data from the clicked link.

```
return MaterialApp(
      theme: _lightTheme,
      darkTheme: _darkTheme,
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        // Do magic here,
      },
    );
```

I know issue is getting un-necessarily complicated or I might be missing something basic to implement it.

EDIT: 1
**FOUND WORK AROUND**

Solution that worked for me:

use a mixture of `onGenerateRoute` and `home`.
`onGenerateRoute` have `RouteSetting` which has the information for the clicked deep link, considering of what `host` you provided.

Will be writing a dedicated/detailed answer soon to handle various cases for different OS.

Comment: Have you found a solution? please do share here, i need one